# How can i do a hierarchy data based on a value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I've this table with the following data

```
 Cat     CatID        Tag
 0         1        LapTop
 1         2         Mac
 1         3         HP
 1         4         Acer
 1         5         Sony
 1         6         DELL
 6         7         Latitude
 6         8         Vostro
 6         9         inspiron
 6         10        xps
```

Based on the value Cat and CatID i want to get this result
if `Cat=0` i want to display the value in a column and if `CatID=Cat` i want to display the value in another column as bellow the value that i want to insert in a new table

```
 Tag       Libelle    Type
 LapTop     Mac
 LapTop     HP
 LapTop     Acer
 LapTop     Sony
 LapTop     DELL      Latitude
 LapTop     DELL      Vostro
 LapTop     DELL      inspiron
 LapTop     DELL      xps
```

Comment: How come "LapTop" has occurred 8 times? whereas CatID=Cat has 5 occurrence only?   Apart from "DELL" and "LaoTop" none of them matched CatID=Cat then how other's displayed in your result example?

Comment: @TejuMB The structure of the data is hierarchical. `Tag` column represents the parent node, `Libelle` the children and `Type` the grandchildren.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `INNER` and `LEFT` join operations can produce the desired result set:

```
SELECT t1.Tag, t2.Tag AS Libelle, 
       COALESCE(t3.Tag, '') AS Type
FROM mytable AS t1
INNER JOIN mytable AS t2 ON t1.CatID = t2.Cat
LEFT JOIN mytable AS t3 ON t2.CatID = t3.Cat
WHERE t1.Cat = 0
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9b76a/1)